# What can I use to monitor which IP address w/name resolution is connected to each PID?

Tags: linux, process, ip-address, netstat, domain-name-system

This would be for under Linux particularly.

Is there a tool out there, or a script that I could use to monitor IP connections--with name resolution--and, see which process they're connected to?

Right now I'm using this:

```
watch -d netstat -peeW --numeric-hosts --inet
```

But that doesn't give me host resolution.  I was thinking of writing up a script with sed or something, but that seemed like more work than it needed to be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Getting rid of `--numeric-hosts` will tell netstat to do address lookups.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the following

**sudo lsof -i -n -a**

(You could also use fuser)